# How to design a simple database for charitable donations in MS-Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, accounting

I have been asked to build a simple database for my church. Those using the database will need to use the form view only, so I am trying to make it very user friendly. The church has 3 bank account (checking, savings, and allocated). The allocated account is my problem. This account holds money for 4 separate missions, fundraisers, youth, tithes, food, and music.

I need the depositor to be able to go to a form choose an account from a drop down list and if they choose Allocated I need another drop list to be available to show where the funds are going. I can make the list but it will not update my table. No matter which account I choose it sends everything to the Checking account.

It has been years since I first learned Access and now even with a couple of how to books I seem lost...any help is welcome.

Comment: If all else fails, I'm sure software exists already to do this kinda stuff.

Comment: Post to rentacoder.com and you'll have it done for $20 bucks :)

Comment: For $20 bucks you'll be $20 less rich and you'll be no closer to a working solution. I make tons of money cleaning up after the morons who charge $5/hour and don't know their asses from a hole in the ground.

Comment: Yah you do have to be careful, VBA in particular is one of those skills that seems to have a lot of self-appointed "experts", YMMV. The joy of VBA is that is so powerful and easy to learn. The danger of VBA is that it's so powerful and easy to learn:)

Comment: I wouldn't boot up my computer for $20.

Answer (score 1):

There can't be a simple answer to your question, because you didn't ask a ["Answerable" question](http://ed-web3.educ.msu.edu/digitaladvisor/Research/whatanswerable.htm). (Example: How do I create a table, etc.) It seems you are very new to this, so don't be discouraged by the curve. Access can be very non-intuitive, but it's actually quite easy with a little guidance.
I would suggest to you that you isolate one thing you need to do to get to the solution and ask the question. Post a new thread for each question. It is not unexpected to ask many many question on your first project. But that is how you learn.
Something else to ponder is that as a non-profit you might be able to find someone willing to donate their time, just be careful when soliciting help on a *financial* database. It's very important that you don't accidentally reveal real data. If someone asks you for a populated example, make sure you only provide "test" data. I'm sure your contributors and members will appreciate your discretion.
If you do want more in depth help you can reach me via the information in my profile, I try to help non-profits out when and where I can. 
Best of Luck!

Edit: Another thing to consider is that Microsoft has generously made a lot of "template" databases available that you might would give you an idea or too. Here is a link to the ["Charitable Contributions"](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/TC010185821033.aspx?pid=CT102144001033) one.

Answer (score 1):

Simple is always in the eye of the beholder. It simple to write some text in a word processor, but try writing word to allow this.

The idea and concept of splitting out funds to several banks accounts is a classic relational database problem that darn near every developer has to deal with. As for ms-access, here is a screen shot of church system I wrote in ms-access that does exactly as you ask:

[image]

Note how in the above there also a custom menu bar so users don’t EVER see the ms-access interface. So, you can build and make your custom interface just about anyway you want. Note that once the above donations are completed and posted, then users can’t change the posted data. Note how for EACH donation we have a form on the right side that allows one to SPLIT out the funds to each different account.

In the above I deployed the application as multi-user so the church did not have to purchase ms-access for each workstation.

The table structure used in the above to allow weekly batch jobs and the ability to distribute funds to multiple accounts is as follows:

[image]
<sub>(source: [kallal.ca](http://www.kallal.ca/web1a/cbatch.png))</sub>

Keep in mind there is MANY more related tables to handle all of the business needs of a church system. However, the above table structure will give you the idea as to how you can allow funds to be split out into different accounts. And, this allows you to produce monthly accounting reports in which the data is then entered into their accounting system.

Answer (score 0):

Is the second drop-down/where the funds are going have a control source? This should be the field in the table where you want to store this second value.